# Google Maps disappears after 1 second

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am trying to implement the Google Maps API

```
<div id="mapContainer">
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>

#mapContainer {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 2.5%;
  margin-top: 2.5%;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

And here is the initialisation (taken from Google's API website):

```
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=***&callback=initMap" sync defer></script>
```

The problem is this: when the page loads, the map shows for 1 second and then it disappears. Not only this, but the whole `<div id="map"></div>` DOM element is removed from the page (checked with Dev Tools) and `js?key=***&callback=initMap:35 Google Maps API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError` error gets thrown. How can I fix this?

**Key is hashed on purpose.

Comment: follow the instructions here to create it correctly: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key you might have created the wrong sort of google project.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294128/how-can-i-get-google-map-api-v3-key). It seems you haven't finished activating the key.

Comment: tried your code with my key in fiddle and it works smoth